# Color display issue with oh-my-zsh agnoster theme

Tags: themes, zsh

I have set up oh-my-zsh on RHEL machine running red-hat and I am using agnoster theme. But there seems to be some problem and on terminal the things are not properly displayed. Below is how it is displayed:

{black}{default} adarshs@adarshs {blue}{black}⮀{black} ~/.oh-my-zsh {yellow}{blue}⮀{black} ⭠ master± {yellow}⮀

It seems to me that there is some issue with the color scheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the readme! https://gist.github.com/agnoster/3712874

You need to install Powerline fonts.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same customisations myself and realised that you can change the color settings not just by tweaking the themse settings but also from the Terminal 'Preferences'

Mine were the default ones, I did some searching and accidentally caught my attention to these colors. Tweaking a bit of those, worked like a charm for me.

So the prerequisites are:

- Have Powerline Fonts installed.
- Have selected at least one of those font (on terminal/iTerm either)
- If you have installed but not selected one of those fonts, symbols may not work correctly.

[image: terminal_pref_colors]